# Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database linked up to two apps, one being an iOS app and another being a web app coded in node.js which is a basic algorithm that sets data to the database. When ever i am running the algorithm i am confronted with-

> **Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase
>   App.initializeApp().**
>       at Error (native)
>       at R (/Users/dd/Desktop/Code/NODE/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:22:335)
>       at a (/Users/dd/Desktop/Code/NODE/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:20:68)
>       at Object.c [as database] (/Users/dd/Desktop/Code/NODE/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:21:447)
>       at Object. (/Users/dd/Desktop/Code/NODE/Bot.js:24:25)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:509:3 dd-mac:NODE dd$

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 112):

You are probably invoking `firebase` before the app is initialized. All calls to `firebase` must come *after* `.initializeApp();`

```js
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: This was my problem BUT it wasn't because of the line by line order of the code, but rather the order of my IMPORTS. I was importing my code that uses firebase before my code that initialized it.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?authuser=1#automatically_populated_environment_variables

Comment: What do you mean the order of your imports?   I have tried this- ```import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';``` then ```import "@react-native-firebase/database"``` and it doesn't work

Comment: This was my problem too, but for me it was happening due to Firebase being initialised in my own firebase.js file (which imports from `firebase`) and, in another module, I was accidentally importing from `firebase` instead of my (initialised) `./firebase`.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using angular here is a solution.

Complete tutorial **source [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-firebase-login-registration-by-email-and-password/)**

Use **initializeApp** before @NgModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthenticateService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AuthenticateService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: A library agnostic question shouldn't be answered with a library specific answer.

Comment: @mesqueeb this could be an error that only occurs in angular so then it would be fine to answer language-specific.

Comment: This is no longer supported because Angular/Firebase/Angularfire again made breaking changes. Now you have to initialize using "    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase))," in your imports array. Initializing outside of ngModule gives an error now. No idea how to fix this issue now.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using **React Native**, this error can also happen if you did not configure the native side properly.

Documentation here: https://rnfirebase.io/

**Android**

First, download the `google-services.json` file and place it inside of your project at the following location: `/android/app/google-services.json`.

Then, add the google-services plugin as a dependency inside of your `/android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    // Add me --- /\
  }
}
```

Lastly, execute the plugin by adding the following to your `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line
```

**iOS**

First, Add your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to the project through xcode. Make sure it shows up in build phases so you know it's added to the project and not just the folder.

Then, open your `/ios/{projectName}/AppDelegate.m` file, and add the following:

At the top of the file, import the Firebase SDK:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

Within your existing didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, add the following to the top of the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Add me --- \/
  [FIRApp configure];
  // Add me --- /\
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you using Dart and Flutter

1. add firebase_core  dependency to pubspac.ymal.
2. go to main.dart
3. import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

4.add **async** in main()

follow my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var fsconnect = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  myget() async {
    var d = await fsconnect.collection("students").get();
    // print(d.docs[0].data());

    for (var i in d.docs) {
      print(i.data());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Firebase Firestore App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('send data'),
            onPressed: () {
              fsconnect.collection("students").add({
                'name': 'sarah',
                'title': 'xyz',
                'email': 'sarah@gmail.com',
              });
              print("send ..");
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('get data'),
            onPressed: () {
              myget();
              print("get data ...");
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: does this work for you. I tried same thing adding async in Main. Doesn't solve the issue. Now I follow [link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire) . The link also doesn't solve. getting the error Firebase is not initialized.

Comment: That solution didn't work for me either. I did everything correctly and according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0jFkP0A3B0 but unfortunately I still get the error message...

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue following Firebase's online guide found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

The section heading "Initialize multiple apps" is misleading as the first example under this heading actually demonstrates how to initialize a single, default app. Here's said example:

```
// Initialize the default app
var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

console.log(defaultApp.name);  // "[DEFAULT]"

// Retrieve services via the defaultApp variable...
var defaultAuth = defaultApp.auth();
var defaultDatabase = defaultApp.database();

// ... or use the equivalent shorthand notation
defaultAuth = admin.auth();
defaultDatabase = admin.database();
```

If you are migrating from the previous 2.x SDK you will have to update the way you access the database as shown above, or you will get the, `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]'` error.

Google has better documentation at the following:

1. INITIALIZE: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start
2. SAVE: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data
3. RETRIEVE:
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 7):

My problem was because I added a second parameter:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'reservas')
```

if I remove the second parameter it works fine:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Comment: Does it matter if you use firebase.initializeApp as opposed to AngularFireModule.initializeApp

Comment: The second parameter creates a new "app" handle. If one omits that parameter, the app name `[DEFAULT]` is implied, thus "the default app". Why this mattered for you is likely that code can implicitly use the default by eg. `firebase.firestore()` whereas with the custom "app" (first) the return value, an "app handle" must be passed around.

I use both ways. The default for the main web app and the named variant within a library.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be best answer but, I had to initialize app with admin and firebase like below. I use admin for it's own purposes and firebase as well.

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// Get the Auth service for the default app
var authService = firebase.auth();

 function createUserWithEmailAndPassword(request, response) {
        const email = request.query.email;
        const password = request.query.password;
        if (!email) {
            response.send("query.email is required.");
            return;
        }
        if (!password) {
            response.send("query.password is required.");
            return;
        }
        return authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(success => {
                let responseJson = JSON.stringify(success);
                console.log("createUserWithEmailAndPassword.responseJson", responseJson);
                response.send(responseJson);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                let errorJson = JSON.stringify(error);
                console.log("createUserWithEmailAndPassword.errorJson", errorJson);
                response.send(errorJson);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Flutter web**

For me the error occurred when I run my application in "release" mode

`flutter run -d chrome --release`

and when I deployed the application on the Firebase hosting

`firebase deploy`

**Solution**

Since I initialized Firebase in the index.html, I had to change the implementation order of firebase and main.dart.js

```
<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "1:xxxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

//moved below firebase init
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This solves the issue

Answer (score 4):

If you are on react native and developing for IOS then I think you forgot the linking steps of firebase module.

follow the below steps..!

open your `/ios/{projectName}/AppDelegate.m` file, and add the following:

At the top of the file, import the Firebase SDK:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

Within your existing `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, add the following to the top of the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Add this  --- \/
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  // Add me --- /\
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer may already be given somewhere but **here is my take to this error which may be thrown for multiple reasons**:

1. Default app is initialized after the other one. Correct way is to initialize the default app first and then the rest.
2. `firebase.apps.app()` is being called before default app initialization. This code is basically returning the default app instance. Since it is not present, hence the error.
3. Lastly, you are initializing other firebase services like auth, database, firestore, etc before app is initialized.

Comment: For me it was #3. I had named exports `{firebaseClient, dbClient,authClient,storageClient}` where the individual services were defined as `const dbClient = firebaseClient.firestore(); ...`.

Comment: Hadn't heard of 1. Will check!

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting out a *react-native* app and seeing this issue, then you have to follow all the instructions listed in firebase (when you setup iOS/android app) or the instructions @ [React-native google auth android DEVELOPER_ERROR Code 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64109012/234110) question

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error while working with iOS. Hope you have already installed the Firebase using pods. You need to do the following.
Open the Xcode and open AppDelegate.m file and import

```
#import "FIRApp.h"
```

Now call configure method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method

```
  [FIRApp configure];
```

Now run your app. It should work. Here is doc [link](https://rnfirebase.io/)

Answer (score 1):

YOU CALL THIS IN JADE: firebase.initializeApp(config); IN THE BEGIN OF THE FUNC

```
script.
    function signInWithGoogle() {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
        .then(function (data){
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question stated.

Comment: @akauppi It is related. I used this solution in angular. Instead of writing in app module, I just included in the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you are trying to use firebase function before it has successfully initialised

Fix:

Place the function you want to call inside setInterval block such that the function is called only once the app has been initialised:

```
 let isFirebaseAppDefined = false;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (!isFirebaseAppDefined) {
        if (firebase.app()) {

          // Function that needs to run after the initialisation comes here
          // Example re-captcha verifier or other auth function

          isFirebaseAppDefined = true;
        }
      }
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution is here.

use APP_INITIALIZER

https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

```
export function appInitializer() {
  return () => firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

...
@NgModule({
 ...
 providers: [{
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: () => appInitializer
   multi: true
  }]
 })
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in ios when I updated the React Native version, add this instruction in method: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from file: `ios/{AppName}/AppDelegate.m`

```
   if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
     [FIRApp configure];
   }
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

in my case i was using

```
getAuth()
getFirestore()
```

with out passing the app instead use it like

```js
const app = initializeApp(config);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Initialize app in the app.module.ts

```js
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
```

This will clear the error.
You can use firebase.database() without any errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When I tried adding my flutter web app to firebase I took the Script tags google gave me in the setup process and pasted them into my index.html. That didn't work for me even AFTER I modified my main.dart with the following lines in the main method:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp());
```

Using the Script in the format posted here I got it working:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web

If there are other people having the same issue and blindly copying the Script Tags Google gives you in the Firebase Setup.... this helped me. Just get it into the format posted by FlutterFire.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

## Using npm

npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app

## Using Yarn

yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

step 2:
Generating Android credentials in https://console.firebase.google.com/
The "Android package name" must match your local project's package name which can be found inside of the manifest tag within the /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file within your project.

Download the google-services.json file and place it inside of your project at the following location: /android/app/google-services.json.

step3:
and then add the google-services plugin as a dependency inside of your /android/build.gradle file:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

Lastly, execute the plugin by adding the following to your /android/app/build.gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line

That's all....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
https://github.com/abhi3700/My_Learning_Databases/tree/main/Firebase#initialize-firestore

```js
const fs = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../../../helper/serviceAccountKey.json");

let db = null;

// initialize firebase
if (!fs.apps.length) {
  fs.initializeApp({
    credential: fs.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    // name: "zippy-mvp2",
  });

  db = fs.firestore();

  // allow undefined values.
  db.settings({
    ignoreUndefinedProperties: true,
  });
} else {
  db = fs.app().firestore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using react js

My problem was I had put the firebase folder in my main project folder instead of the /src folder.

Once I moved the folder it worked perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic with angular, in my case were imports from getAuth and updateProfile, the route names are different by versions

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this error with a newly created react app by adding

```
import firebase from "./firebase";
```

as the first import in App.js to fix the error.

```
import firebase from "./firebase";
import { getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

function App() {
  const auth = getAuth();

return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <p>HW </p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The firebase initialisation code is in firebase.js in the same directory as App.js.

Answer (score 0):

My problem in AngularFire 7.0 was incorrect imports in app.module.ts

`import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';`

should be

`import { getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';`

```
// imports should be from '@angular/fire/...'
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getDatabase, provideDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
// wrong imports from 'firebase/...'
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database'; // wrong
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'; // wrong

    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't put

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Statment in the App level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

For you guys using Vue or Nuxt, separate the listener and put the initialization codes inside the `onBeforeMount` hook.

```
const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  console.log('Requesting notification permission...')
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission()
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.')
  }
}

const initFcm = async () => {
  await requestNotificationPermission()

  const app = await initializeApp(config.public.firebase)
  const messaging = getMessaging(app)

  try {
    const vapidKey = config.public.firebase.vapidKey
    let currentToken: Nullish<string>
    currentToken = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey })

    if (!currentToken) {
      console.log(
        'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.',
      )
    } else {
      await $fetch('/api/auth/profile', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: { fcm_token: currentToken },
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', error)
  }
}

const notifications = ref<NotificationPayload[]>([])

onBeforeMount(() => initFcm())
onMounted(() => {
  const messaging = getMessaging()
  onMessage(messaging, (payload: NotificationPayload) => {
    notifications.value.unshift(payload)
    toast.add({
      title: payload.notification.title,
      description: payload.notification.body,
      click: () => {
        notifications.value = notifications.value.filter(
          (n) => n.messageId !== payload.messageId,
        )
      },
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue 3 I got this message after I added this import to my first .vue file that gets loaded.

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

In my project I have a firebase.js file that loads firebase for my application...

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    // enter your own configs here
  };

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = firebaseApp.firestore()
const userCollection = db.collection('users')

export const createUser = user => {
    return userCollection.add(user)
}

export const getUser = async id => {
    const user = await userCollection.doc(id).get();
    return user.exists ? user.data() : null
}

export const updateUser = (id, user) => {
    return userCollection.doc(id).update(user)
}

export const deleteUser = id => {
    return userCollection.doc(id).delete()
}
```

To resolve this issue I added

```
import './firebase';
```

within my main.js file (see below). This ensures the firebase application is loaded within our Vue application before we try using the firebase import within the .vue files.

```
// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

// Components
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import './firebase';

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think This Error is Arrived Because of You are using Class Component in Respective React Platform that Doesn't get Proper Configuration.
So You Write Configuration in componentWillMount().

```
componetWillMount() {
const config = {
apiKey: “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”,
authDomain: “auth-bdcdc.firebaseapp.com 20”,
databaseURL: “https://auth-bdcdc.firebaseio.com 7”,
projectId: “auth-bdcdc”,
storageBucket: “auth-bdcdc.appspot.com 2”,
messagingSenderId: “xxxxxxxxxx”
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was remplace this

```
const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
    };
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

to this.....

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js";
firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
    });
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution!

Follow these steps:

[Flutter Firebase and Android issue - unable to Initialise. Cannot find google-services.json with latest migration instructions executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804012/flutter-firebase-and-android-issue-unable-to-initialise-cannot-find-google-se)

After that, execute:

```
flutter build apk --debug
flutter build apk --profile
flutter build apk --release
```

and then, run app! it works for me!

Comment: Can you summarize the steps in your link, or describe why this solution fixed the issue? As it stands, this neither provides a solution nor provides any explanation to solve the OP's problem.