# How to initialize firebase in angular 8?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am new to firebase.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase. npm install in my angular8& ionic4 package for performance monitoring and analytics. some module getting error. I couldn't solve my problem.

Error:-

```
index.cjs.js:638 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
at app (http://192.168.43.123:8100/vendor.js:86420:33)
at Object.serviceNamespace [as performance] (http://192.168.43.123:8100/vendor.js:86471:51)
at Module../src/app/pages/wcsm/wcsm.page.ts (http://192.168.43.123:8100/main.js:12917:69)
at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.123:8100/runtime.js:85:30)
at Module../src/app/components/popup/popup.component.ts (http://192.168.43.123:8100/main.js:8795:80)
at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.123:8100/runtime.js:85:30)
at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (http://192.168.43.123:8100/main.js:1284:105)
at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.123:8100/runtime.js:85:30)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (http://192.168.43.123:8100/main.js:1808:72)
at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.43.123:8100/runtime.js:85:30)
```

app.modules.ts

```
 import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
 import 'firebase/analytics';
 import 'firebase/performance';
 import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase-config';
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const analytics= firebase.analytics();
 const perf = firebase.performance();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that you have already Project ready on Firebase and firebase installed in your Angular Project via npm commands**

*Step 1* :
Create a file `manifest.json` in your `src` directory of Angular Project.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "gcm_sender_id": "SENDER_ID"  -- Put your sender Id here from firebase app
}
```

*Step 2* :
Add your `manifest` file link in `index.html` like this

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="manifest"  href="./manifest.json">
 </head>
```

*Step 3 :*
Make sure you have added your `manifest` file in `angular.json` file

**angular.json**

```
    {
     "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",  //worker file , make sure you have this in src 
      "src/manifest.json" 
    }
```

*Step 4:* Initialize firebase in `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
 import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
 var config = {
    apiKey: "", -- put values accordingly
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

If you are using FireModule then make sure to add it in `imports` of `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule, 
    AngularFireMessagingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
  ]
```

*Step 5:* If you are using `service`  or `pipes` make sure to put them in `providers`

**app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [
    MessageService, AsyncPipe
  ]
```

*Step 6:*  Your `worker` file should look like this normally named `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
    --import versions according your machine
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js'); 
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');

    var config = {
    apiKey: "", -- put values accordingly
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.   I am not using angular/fire npm. Due to  build time getting unknown error.   I also tried CDN method, couldn't call performance trace function. Sometimes getting analytics not a function error. I tried every possible way I couldn't figure out.

Comment: did you checked this ?                       
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali

Comment: Yes, already tried. but same error.   Popup component included module not working.

Comment: Did you add pop up  component name in entry points array of relevant module ?

Comment: If you are treating it as a Pop up Modal then you should add component name in  entry points array

Comment: I have added entryComponents[]. Main problem is firebase initialization