# React-native google auth android DEVELOPER_ERROR Code 10

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

### What I did:

`react-native init testAuthGoogle && cd testAuthGoogle && (cd android; ./gradlew signingReport)` to create a new project and show the SHA1

```sh
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /Users/anand/ws/rn01/testAuthGoogle/android/app/debug.keystore
Alias: androiddebugkey
MD5: 20:F4:61:48:B7:2D:8E:5E:5C:A2:3D:37:A4:F4:14:90
SHA1: 55:88:11:06:2E:A3:CC:2C:4A:0D:EE:78:76:88:A6:F3:8C:AB:FF:88
SHA-256: FA:C6:17:45:DC:09:03:78:6F:B9:ED:E6:2A:96:2B:39:9F:73:48:F0:BB:6F:89:9B:83:32:66:75:91:03:3B:9C
Valid until: Tuesday, April 30, 2052
```

Copied the SHA1 into firebase and created the android app
[image: Firebase android app with support email]

Downloaded the `google-services.json` file to `android/app/google-services.json`

In `android/build.gradle`:

- Added dependency : `classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")`

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

- Apply plugin: `apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"`
- Added dependencies `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'` and `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'`

Installed other dependencies:

```sh
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/auth @react-native-community/google-signin
```

Copied the `client_id` from `google-services.json` file to use it in app.js.
[image: google-service.json with client_id]

Code change in `app.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton, statusCodes } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: '532405863926-94v4mgqg18ajc2g7tk6ttghvsnilooee.apps.googleusercontent.com' });
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [authErr, setAuthErr] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => setUser(user)), []);
  onGoogleSignOut = async () => await auth().signOut()
  getAuthErrorSnip = () => authErr ? <Text>{JSON.stringify(authErr)}</Text> : null
  onGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      await auth().signInWithCredential(auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(user.idToken));
    } catch (error) {
      setAuthErr(error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" style={styles.scrollView}>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
            <GoogleSigninButton onPress={onGoogleSignIn} ></GoogleSigninButton>
            {getAuthErrorSnip()}
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  }
});

export default App;
```

What I see when i did `react-native run-android` and click on `Sign in`:
[image: Android phone screenshot]

Comment: https://app.slack.com/client/T094HDHDX/C1BL01PS7

Comment: you pick the wrong SHA1 key. Take the SHA1 key under the debug variant, and then redownload the google JSON file and rebuild your app

Comment: I am not using any firebase sdk for google login either in ios or in android and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is an error related to your client_id or SHA-1 configuration, check out this [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360#issuecomment-381648685) on github related to the same error.

By looking at the screenshots and code you have shared, it looks to me you are using wrong client_id, for **google web client**, I believe you should be using

`client_id` with `client_type : 3`

instead of

`client_id` with `client_type : 1`

so try fixing your `client_id` in `app.js` file and it should work.