# 'No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created' even though initializeApp is called

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to add Firebase (Firestore) to my Nuxt project, however I am recieving the following error when initialising a const from `firebase.firestore()` in my `index.vue` file:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been
> created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

I have installed Firebase in my project and also the module (`@nuxtjs/firebase`).

My nuxt.config.js file looks like this:

```
export default {

...

plugins: ['~/plugins/firebase.js'],

components: true,

buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
],

modules: [],

...

}
```

And my firebase.js file is within my plugins folder as follows:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const config = {
    ...
}

let app = null
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

export default firebase
```

I've compared the above to other examples online and haven't spotted any issues. However I'm new to everything from Nuxt to Firebase, so I may be missing something obvious. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200816/2185093

Comment: @Dan I had a look at that post, however I can't understand why `const firestore = firebase.firestore()` in my store/index.js file is being called before `app = firebase.initializeApp(config)` which is referenced in my `nuxt.config.js` file as `plugins: ['~/plugins/firebase.js']`. Could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: If I move the initialisation code to the `firebase.js` file, it works and the error is gone, but I should be able to keep this code referenced as a plugin, no?

Comment: I don't use this stack, but maybe it's a little different from the [docs example](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens if you call `initializeApp()` more than once on a single firebase app.  If you're working with a single firebase db, make sure to initialize it when your app starts.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11351) this snippet for **firebase.js** should work:

```
import fb from "firebase/app"
export const firebase = !fb.apps.length ? fb.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : fb.app()

// somecomponent.js
import {firebase} from "../firebase.js"

// do your firebase stuff here
```

*Credit to [@Brunocrosier](https://github.com/brunocrosier) with [his post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11351#discussioncomment-17797); even though this snippet isn't case-specific, I decided to include it for the sake of completeness.*

---

Besides this thread - generally speaking, `Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).` is often a result of of either calling `firebase.` before initializing via `.initializeApp();` or by calling `.initializeApp()` multiple times (*for example **Next.js** might try to initialize it on the back- as well as the frontend - which seems to be the case in your code*) within your firebase app.

Hence as a solution I highly suggest to move your initialization to the **firebase.js** file in order to initialize it directly when your app starts.

---

For **further reading** purposes:

- [The nuxt/firebase documentation](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started/)
- [Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali/49200816#49200816)
- [The previously mentioned GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11351)
- [FireBase JavaScript documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you try to access firestore before initializing the firebase. So as default we can check if firebase is initialized or not by `firebase.apps.length` but it's not a good practice to initialize firebase each and every time.

so if you are only using firestore then in your plugin you can export firestore directly after initialization like following,

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const config = {
    ...
}

let app = null
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

export default firebase.firestore()
```

But since you are working with nuxt there is special nuxt package called [firebase/nuxt](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/)

with that installed you can define your configuration in nuxt config inside the module section as bellow,

```
modules: [
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          apiKey: '<apiKey>',
          authDomain: '<authDomain>',
          databaseURL: '<databaseURL>',
          projectId: '<projectId>',
          storageBucket: '<storageBucket>',
          messagingSenderId: '<messagingSenderId>',
          appId: '<appId>',
          measurementId: '<measurementId>'
        },
        services: {
          auth: true // Just as example. Can be any other service.
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
```

I think it is a better way to use firebase inside the nuxt.js