# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I got this problem when I try to setup firebase whit next.js. I don't know what's going on.

[image]

**firebase.js file**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/firestore';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
  });
}
export default firebase;
```

I also create a `.env.local` and I added environment variables.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali

Comment: I try that but I got the same issue

Comment: How does your _app.js look like?