# Share firebase config parent and submodule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Question:
Is it possible to share an app config, that was configured in the parent with an imported submodule in JavaScript?

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
firebase.initializeApp(window.config);


import { someView } from "@custom-package/views";


someView()
```

```js
//within the package @custom-package/views

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
const someView = ()=>{
   //some firestore query
   firebase.firestore().....
}

export default {
   someView
}
```

Currently, I'm getting this error:

```js
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)
```

As an additional info, I can share, that `@custom-package/views` is bundled with webpack and served as a private NPM package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `firebase.initializeApp(window.config);` before you call the `firestore` in your `@custom-package/views`.

The error you mentioned usually happens when firebase calls were made before invoking firebase app initialization. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali) that that is the case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. As you can see in my example, I'm calling it it before calling `@custom-package/views`